Drag window from one Mac to another Mac when both Macs are using linked keyboard and mouse
Is it possible to drag window between two macs when both macs are using linked keyboard and mouse. I'm using iMac and Mac Mini + Studio Display. Both are being controlled via single keyboard and m ouse (link keyboard and mouse).
Please note that this answer Is there a keyboard shortcut to move a window from one monitor to another? is not applicable when you use link keyboard and mouse.
